# What is the difference between a Windows system image and a clone?

Tags: windows-7, backup, clone, system-restore, clonezilla

What is the difference between a Windows system image *(generated using Control Panel -> Backup and Restore -> Create a System Image)* created in Windows 7 SP1, versus creating a clone using a tool like [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

Both cloning and imaging create an exact record of your drive or partition.

When you clone a drive you create an exact copy of it onto another drive, so the two become identical. Imaging on the other hand copies all the information you have stored on the drive into a single, compressed, but still relatively large file.

Each of these are suitable for a different purpose too. For instance, if you want to make a backup of your data system image will suite better, while cloning is used mainly for transferring the whole OS to another internal drive and after that replacing the old with the new drive.

Comment: Thanks!  I thought a Windows 7 system image, coupled with the Windows 7 Recovery CD, can be used to transfer the whole OS to a new drive.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: You're welcome! :) Yes, you can transfer the OS with a System Image and a Recovery Disc, but it will take more time and it's more complicated compared to a simple cloning. You can check for some online tutorials for each of the two, for instance [System Image+Recovery Disc](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/675-system-image-recovery.html) and [cloning with Acronis True Image WD Edition](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=RQqbsD).